# How to get column such as that By collection

Tags: collection, filter, sql

I want to get a column like `(datetime % 3600) / 60` as minute，But I use

```
$collection->columns('(datetime%3600)/60 as minute')
```

But I got SQL is `` `main_table`.`datetime%3600/60` AS `minute` ``

How I fixed It?

Comment: Welcome to SE, could you add more info on the qst. It's not clear enough.

Comment: Please give some more detail about your issue and also put your detail code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Zend_Db_Expr` for expressions instead of column names:

```
columns(new Zend_Db_Expr('(datetime%3600)/60 as minute'))
```